# generating a bulletprooh hashCode for Hibernate composite key

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table whose PK consists of two short varchars (15 and 5) and one datetime field.

My thoughts on creating a hashCode was to formate the datetime to something like yyyyMMddHHmmss and then concatenate it with the other two fields using some delimiter (e.g. _) and then ask for the hash code on that string.

Was wondering if there may be a more elegant approach.

Thanks

Comment: This question has nothing to do with hibernate.  Just follow best practice for writing a hashcode (which has been asked/answered many times).  Essentially, to compute a hashcode for an object with multiple fields, compute the hashcode for each individual field and combine them in some way (add them, xor them, etc.).

Comment: my concern is that the addition of two numbers will produce the same result as the addition of another two completely different numbers.  e.g.  5 + 6 = 7 + 4.  that is why i hesitate to use this method

Comment: It is legal for two objects to produce the same hash code; this is called a hash collision, and cannot be avoided in most cases.  Data structures which depend on hash codes must be prepared for dealing with hash collions, using such techniques as bucket chaining or linear probing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All depends on what you mean by "bulletproof".  If you just mean it can be used as the `hashCode` of a Java object, then it should be fine.  Doesn't Hibernate return a datetime as a java `Date`?  If so, just use `hashCode` on that `Date`.  You can xor (or add, ...) with the other `hashCode`s instead of concatenating and hashing, it may be a bit faster.

If by "bulletproof" you need a cryptographically secure hash, then you need to do more.

Comment: what i mean by "bulletproof" is a guarantee that there won't be dupes or false positives.  i am skeptical to do a simple addition of each field's hashcode because it is possible to have two tuples of completely different attributes whose added hashcodes end up being the same.  like in the example 5 + 6 = 7 + 4.

Comment: Hashcodes are not set up so that "there won't be duplicates" - you are presumably taking something that is N bytes long and putting it through an algorithm to produce something that is M bytes long, where N is greater than M.  If it is possible to represent all possible values of N in an encoded fashion in M bytes, more power to you, but in general a given hash value might stand for more than one of the original strings.

Comment: let me put it this way, and here is where Hibernate comes into play for JimN:  i am not exactly sure which role hashCode will play in the PK identification by Hibernate but all i want to do is make sure that X-Y-Z is never, ever confused with A-B-C even if the two entirely different tuples' hash codes may be the same.  what i am hoping is that the overridden equals method is what will make sure that.  am i right?  thanks

Comment: @foampile: yes, `hashCode` is only a hint (If the hashes are different, it is definitely not the same object.  If the hashes are equal, it *might* be the same object).  `equals` is the code that matters.

Comment: THANKS Keith -- that's what I wanted to know